# Disk weapons in the original book, The Day of the Triffids

Tags: novel, the-day-of-the-triffids

I read the 1951 novel by the English science fiction author John Wyndham many years ago. I no longer have a copy.

My memory is that the first effective weapon that was used against the triffids was a gun that fired metal disks at them and chopped off their stinging tentacles. What I can't remember is the origin of the weapons. I'm sure that they already existed before the meteor shower (maybe as toys or hunting weapons?) and merely had to be adapted.

Can anyone remind me of the in-story origin of these disk-firing weapons as described in the original novel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The spring-guns existed before the 'incident' and were used for the purposes of keeping triffids under control in tropical and jungle regions.

> In temperate countries, where man had succeeded in putting most forms of nature save his own under a reasonable degree of restraint, the status of the triffid was thus made quite clear. But **in the tropics, particularly in the dense forest areas, they quickly became a scourge.**
>
> Dealing with them became a serious problem in such regions. The most
> favoured method was to shoot the top off the stem, and the sting with
> it. The jungle natives took to carrying long, light poles mounted with
> hooked knives which they used effectively if they could get their
> blows in first – but not at all if the triffid had a chance to sway
> forward and increase its range by an unexpected four or five feet.
> Before long, however, **these pike-like devices were mostly superseded
> by spring-operated guns of various types. Most of them shot spinning
> discs, crosses, or small boomerangs of thin steel. As a rule they were
> inaccurate above about twelve yards, though capable of slicing a
> triffid stem neatly at twenty-five if they hit it. Their invention
> pleased both the authorities – who had an almost unanimous distaste
> for the indiscriminate toting of rifles – and the users who found the
> missiles of razor-blade steel far cheaper and lighter than cartridges,
> and admirably adaptable to silent banditry.**
>
> <sub><sup>The Day of the Triffids: Chapter 2 - The Coming of the Triffids</sup></sub>

Comment: If memory serves, tropical botanists use similar devices to clip off samples of foliage from trees that are too tall to reach.

Comment: I looked for references to disks being used to sample foliage from canopy trees, but didn't find one. I did locate several references to shotguns being used for this purpose, including [this one](https://betsyladyzhets.com/2018/06/28/the-great-brf-tree-project-shotgun-sampling/). It seems that this method is being made obsolete by drone sampling.

Comment: I seem to recall them being called "Skeet Guns" , possibly in the 1980s tv version.